# how to fetch female users to mail in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean

i have a simple dating application am designing, and my users model has two boolean fields for male and female, i want a situation when a user signs up as Male, Female users should be shown to him to add as friends and if its a female too, male users should be shown. my users model is as follow

```
  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :bio,              :null => false, :default => "update whatsup with yourself and click here to edit it"
  t.string :username,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""
  t.boolean :admin
  t.boolean :author
  t.boolean :male
  t.boolean :female
```

and i have implemented the friendship model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller action somewhere, add this bit.

```
 @opposite_sex_users = nil
 if current_user.male && !current_user.female
   @opposite_sex_users = User.where(:male => false, :femail => true)
 elsif !current_user.male && current_user.female
   @opposite_sex_users = User.where(:male => true, :femail => false)
 end
```

---

You haven't really given me enough information to solve your problem unfortunately. Assuming you want to use this in `home` action in pages controller for example, you can do something like this.

```rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @opposite_sex_users = nil
    number_of_users_to_show = 5 # change this to the number of users you want to show
    if current_user.male && !current_user.female
      @opposite_sex_users = User.where(:male => false, :femail => true).sample(number_of_users_to_show)
    elsif !current_user.male && current_user.female
      @opposite_sex_users = User.where(:male => true, :femail => false).sample(number_of_users_to_show)
    end
  end
end
```

And in your routes,

```rb
root :to => "pages#home"
```

And in your views/pages/home.html.erb

```rb
<%- @opposite_sex_users.each do |user| %>
  <!-- displays user email %>
  <%= user.username %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: how do i make use of this in my views please?

Comment: Which controller and action do you want to use it on?

Comment: i want a situation if a logged in male user, if he visits the index page showing all users he would be shown female users and if a female user, the opposite occurs  thanks

Comment: See the edited response. I'm sorry, but I had to make some assumptions about your app. But it is really thorough enough that you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: I don't see how it looks like.

Comment: Boss [#<User id: 5, email: "brianking319@gmail.com", bio: "update whatsup with yourself and click here to edit...", username: "Boss", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$CxoUROnggyqB.oapG0b2mujFMUVRS9jZLuVnHJ.SsQsI...", admin: true, author: nil, male: true, female: false, date_of_birth: "1989-05-10", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2013-04-24 22:55:47", last_sign_in_at: "2013-04-24 22:55:47", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2013-04-24 22:53:32", updated_at:]

Comment: instead of outputing Boss alone

Comment: THANKS A LOT garbage collection i figured it out your answer helped me alot

Comment: one more thing how can display them at random?